# Azure Sentinel alerts based on 5 minute intervals of data from KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

I need to come up with a list of results for when admin accounts (which are found using the where statement) are signed into multiple workstations within a span of 5 minutes which would signal suspicious activity within the las 24 hours. Right now, I just have a log of when a distinct event happens every 5 minutes using the necessary information. All I need to do is make it so that the only results that appear are when the same account is signed onto a different workstation within 5 minutes of the last distinct activity with that account on a different workstation but I'm just not sure how to go about that.

```
SecurityEvent
| where Account matches regex "*admin*"
    and AccountType == "User"
    and ((EventID == "4625") or (EventID == "4624"))
| project Account, WorkstationName, IpAddress, EventID, TimeGenerated, Computer
| distinct WorkstationName, Account, IpAddress, EventID, TimeGenerated, Computer
| summarize by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Account, WorkstationName, IpAddress, EventID, Computer
| sort by Account
```

Example data:

```
let Table = datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, Account:string, Computer:string, WorkstationName:string, IPAddress:int, EventID:int) 
[
   7/21/2021, 5:15:00.000 PM, "1", "A", "123", 11.63.24.357, 4624
   7/22/2021, 1:20:00.000 PM, "2", "G", "195", 19.26.83.257, 4624
   7/22/2021, 1:25:00.000 PM, "2", "P", "275", 192.64.9.432, 4624
];
```

Expected output would only be the last 2 logs since the same account was signed into a different computer within a span of 5 minutes. If possible I would also only want to generate one log as a count() for how many times that account was signed into, and on how many different computers within the 5 minute span

Any advice is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample input data and expected output? for the input please use datatable() , this would really help with getting your question answered.

Comment: @Avnera just posted example data if it helps

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
let Table = datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, Account:string, Computer:string, WorkstationName:string, IPAddress:string, EventID:int) 
[
   datetime(2021-07-21 17:15:00.000), "1", "A", "123", "11.63.24.357", 4624,
   datetime(2021-07-22 13:20:00.000), "2", "G", "195", "19.26.83.257", 4624,
   datetime(2021-07-22 13:24:00.000), "2", "P", "275", "192.64.9.432", 4624
];
Table
| summarize EventCount = count(), DistinctComputers= dcount(Computer) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Account
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: That should be what I'm looking for, but when I put it to actual use, for some reason for one account it doesn't count a machine that was used and for another it's counting one machine as 2

Comment: Feel free to modify the input sample data and the expected output. You can use Kusto Explorer to copy any result set as datatable (select the relevant rows and right-click on the result pane and choose "copy as a datatable literal" then also include the exact output that you are expecting.